# How to persist an app on iPhone from Xcode run?

Tags: ios, xcode

I created an app from scratch. I run on my device (iPhone8) from Xcode, and then after one day my app cannot open.

So my questions are:

1. Why local app cannot be opened one day passed? (Not app crashed)
2. How to persist app from Xcode run?
3. How long will an app persist on device from Xcode run? (persist means run well)

PS.

1. run in **DEBUG** mode
2. using my personal account

[image: signing]

Comment: issue is something else, you can keep debug build forever... should not be an issue, might be there is some crash happening on load application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a paid developer membership with Apple (i.e. you have a free membership), your abilities are limited. One way they limit your abilities is by expiring a build from Xcode onto a device in just a couple of days. When the build expires, you just can't launch the app: when you tap its icon, there is a flash and you are back in the springboard.

Once you have a paid membership, you have two choices:

- You can build from Xcode onto a device and it will last considerably longer. But it does still expire after a while.
- You can do an Ad Hoc distribution build. They are very long-lasting (in fact, they might not expire at all).